# How to get the most out of a SFDC Convention?

Tags: salesforcedx

As some of you may know [Salesforce world tour](https://www.salesforce.com/events/worldtour/boston/overview/) is coming to Boston this April!  I am new to the Salesforce developer environment (~6months) and am excited to attend.

**My question to other experienced developers is:**

How can I get the most out of Salesforce World Tour?

Anything like Must see [training sessions](https://www.salesforce.com/events/worldtour/boston/sessions/), or general trivia would be super helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any thing that is "must do" or any trivia. Here are the two biggest takeaways from recent events I've attended:

1. Take sessions that interest you or you can use immediately. If it's anything like TrailheaDX, there is a ton to info to process. Take notes and pictures of presentation slides that interest you.
2. Do not be afraid to chat people up. I wish I had done more of this last year. I've been getting a lot more comfortable with it. I know it's not natural for developers to do this but you'll meet some great people. Easiest way I found was just start a conversation whilst waiting for a session to start or during lunch.

Hope this helps!